# Can't use css in codename one

Tags: eclipse, codenameone

[Css error in codename one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSLM8.jpg)

i'm having issues with the css and when i run the simulator the css is not working.

Answer (score 1):

The `#` selector type isn't supported in Codename One. You need to apply CSS explicitly to UIIDs. The CSS selectors in general for Codename One are far simpler than the full CSS see https://www.codenameone.com/manual/css.html

Just write the UIID of the component you want to style without the `#` character e.g.

```
Button {
    color: pink;
}
```